# Show product_image on new module?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to display product_image on the **custom_page** :

[image]

Please Check my Code.and help me.

> namespace\app\code\Magento\History\Block\HistoryData.php

- I have:

  ```
  <?php
   namespace Magento\History\Block;

   class HistoryData extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
   {    

    public function __constructor(
        ..../Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Item $item....)
   {
        ...
        $item = $item;
        ...
   }


    public function getOrderData() {
       $item = $this->item()->create()->getCollection()- 
     >addFieldToSelect('*');
     return $item;
    }
  }
  ```

  And in this file

> namespace\app\code\Magento\History\view\frontend\templates\history.phtml

```
    <?php 
      $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $orders = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item')- 
     >getCollection();
     $orders->addFieldToSelect('*');
    ?>
     <div class="table-wrapper order-items">
       <table class="data table table-order-items" id="my-orders-table" 
      summary="<?=__('Items Ordered') ?>">
       <caption class="table-caption"><?=__('Items Ordered') ?></caption>
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th class="col image"><?=__('Product Image') ?></th>
             <th class="col name"><?=__('Product Name') ?></th>
             <th class="col qty"><?=__('Qty') ?></th>
             <th class="col price"><?=__('Price') ?></th>
             <th class="col subtotal"><?=__('Subtotal') ?></th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <?php foreach($orders as $item): ?>
              <tr>
                  <td data-th="Product Image" class="col image"><?php echo 
                      $item->getImage(); ?></td>
                 <td data-th="Product Name" class="col name"><?php echo 
                     $item->getName(); ?></td>
                 <td data-th="Qty" class="col qty"><?php echo $item- 
                     >getQtyOrdered(); ?></td>
                 <td data-th="Price" class="col price"><?php echo $item- 
                     >getPrice(); ?></td>
                <td data-th="Subtotal" class="col subtotal"><?php echo 
                     $item->getBaseRowTotalInclTax(); ?></td>
            </tr>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
          </tbody>
       </table>
  </div>
```

Can anyone help the next step to display image?? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to get this done

```
foreach ($orders as $item) {
    $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    $imageUrl = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getImage())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();
}
```

Here You can use **$imageUrl** variable to show the image.

Update your this file

> namespace\app\code\Magento\History\view\frontend\templates\history.phtml

```
    <?php 
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $orders = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item')- 
 >getCollection();
 $orders->addFieldToSelect('*');
?>
 <div class="table-wrapper order-items">
   <table class="data table table-order-items" id="my-orders-table" 
  summary="<?=__('Items Ordered') ?>">
   <caption class="table-caption"><?=__('Items Ordered') ?></caption>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="col image"><?=__('Product Image') ?></th>
         <th class="col name"><?=__('Product Name') ?></th>
         <th class="col qty"><?=__('Qty') ?></th>
         <th class="col price"><?=__('Price') ?></th>
         <th class="col subtotal"><?=__('Subtotal') ?></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php foreach($orders as $item): ?>
       $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());

        $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

        $image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getImage())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();
                ?>
          <tr>
              <td data-th="Product Image" class="col image"><img src="<?= $image_url ?>"  width="75px" height="75px"></td>
             <td data-th="Product Name" class="col name"><?php echo 
                 $item->getName(); ?></td>
             <td data-th="Qty" class="col qty"><?php echo $item- 
                 >getQtyOrdered(); ?></td>
             <td data-th="Price" class="col price"><?php echo $item- 
                 >getPrice(); ?></td>
            <td data-th="Subtotal" class="col subtotal"><?php echo 
                 $item->getBaseRowTotalInclTax(); ?></td>
        </tr>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

I have checked it working.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check

Comment: namespace\app\code\Magento\History\view\frontend\templates\history.phtml , remove your all code. and put my code. which I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Check I have updated my code again.

Comment: Yes...I will. Thaks

Comment: Hi, Please mark as right answer if It's work.

Comment: Hi @Ravi, I have tried and it's still doesn't work. Could you please check it again? Thanks!

Comment: Please check now, I have updated code